# Django: How can I send an email with a description that includes all inputs from a contact form?

Tags: django, email, django-forms, django-views, vs-web-site-project

I have a Django-built website which sends an email to a certain employee after a contact form is submitted. The relevant code in my **views.py** file that does this is as follows:

```
def quote_req(request):
    submitted = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = QuoteForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        description = request.POST['company']
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            # assert false
            send_mail('Contact Form', description, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, ['sample@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/quote/?submitted=True')
    else:
        form = QuoteForm()
        if 'submitted' in request.GET:
            submitted = True

    return render(request, 'quotes/quote.html', {'form': form, 'page_list': Page.objects.all(), 'submitted': submitted})
```

The website successfully sends the email; however, at the moment I am limited to sending only one input from the contact form (in this case, 'company') for the email description (which is utilized in the send_mail command).

Does anyone know if I can modify the request.POST command or use another type of method to send more than one contact form input for the email description (i.e., 'company', 'phone', 'address', etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign all the variables company, phone, address separately then concatenate them as description.
then email description.
See example below:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = QuoteForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    company = request.POST['company']
    phone = request.POST['phone']
    address = request.POST['company']
    description = str(company) + ' '+ str(phone) + ' '+ str(address)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        # assert false
        send_mail('Contact Form', description, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, ['sample@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/quote/?submitted=True')
```

you can also add some text in between like this: 
description = 'The company is ' + str(company) + '. Phone number is '+ str(phone) + '. address is '+ str(address)

Hope that helps.

You can follow me on youtube am sharing all me experience on my channel:

Channel Address is: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCEXgQzMw_DXxk1M4Rlsciag?sub_confirmation=1